# Prevent script dir from being added to sys.path in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to prevent the script's directory from being added to sys.path in python3? I'm getting import conflicts due to the fact that imports are relative in python. A legacy project I'm working with has a file called `logger.py` in the root directory of the script which conflicts with the built-in `logger`.

The custom build system that I use ends up creating symlinks to all the files and dependencies and in production, at runtime we use the `-E` flag to ignore any system set `PYTHONPATH` and set the path to what we want. But running tests/scripts from PyCharm doesn't work because of this conflict.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean to avoid that the *working directory* is added to it? Or do you want to break package imports? Anyway it sounds like your project is simply broken. You should refactor it to use a virtualenv.

Comment: I want the script's directory to NOT appear in sys.path. Like suggested by wpercy below, I could remove the dir (usually the first element of sys.path) from sys.path. I agree project is broken, unfortunately its not something I can simply refactor as this build system is grandfathered in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your script, you can try doing something like:

```
import os
import sys

# the first element of sys.path is an empty string, meant to represent the current directory
sys.path.remove('')
```

then do your normal imports.

Beware, this will cause *all* relative imports from your current directory to fail, potentially causing more problems than your legacy `logger.py`

With regards to your second question, whether or not there's anything that can be done to prevent the directory from being added to `sys.path` in the first place, the short answer is no. From the [Python 3 docs on "module search path"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) :

> sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

I suppose you could set up a symlink from your current working directory to another directory, keep your actual script there, and point the symlink at it. Also from the above docs (emphasis mine):

> On file systems which support symlinks, the directory containing the input script is calculated ***after*** the symlink is followed.

Comment: this is what I'm doing now, wondering if there are any python interpreter flags or environment variables I can set to prevent the script dir from being put in the sys.path

Comment: the short answer is no, there's nothing you can pass to the interpreter that will prevent it from adding the script's own directory to `sys.path`. [Python3 docs on "module search path"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: for the question @fo_x86, based on the doc you can add `-P` flag: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P

Answer (score 3):

The [`-I` option for isolated mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-I) was [added in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-isolated-mode). In the isolated mode the script directory is not added to `sys.path`, but there are also other restrictions such as ignoring the user’s site-packages directory (`-s` option), and all the `PYTHON*` environment variables (`-E` option).

Python 3.11 has a [`-P` option](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P) and a [`PYTHONSAFEPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSAFEPATH) variable which prevent prepending the script directory or other potentially unsafe paths to the `sys.path`.

In Windows a [`._pth` file](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules) can be used to completely override the `sys.path` and activate the isolated mode. This technique is used in the [Windows embeddable package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable).