# Prevent bazel py_test from implicitly depending on files from the same directory

Tags: python, bazel

My bazel py_test rule seems to be able to import files in the same folder for which there was no dependency declared. Is there a way to prevent this? I am running bazel 3.7.2 on linux. Here is an example:

```sh
# Note that foo_test doesn't declare :foo as a dependency
$ cat BUILD
py_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.py"],
)

py_test(
    name = "foo_test",
    srcs = ["foo_test.py"],
)

$ cat foo.py
def foo():
    print("hello")

# However, I can still import and use the library
$ cat foo_test.py
import foo
foo.foo()

$ bazel-3.7.2-linux-x86_64 test :foo_test
<snip>
//:foo_test                                                              PASSED in 0.3s
```

Is there a configuration option that would prevent the `foo_test` rule from implicitly picking up `foo.py`?

Comment: Just to double check: If you run it with `--test_output=streamed` does it print `hello`?

Comment: That is correct. Also, if I modify `foo_test.py` then the test will run again. If I modify `foo.py` then the test will remain cached (I know I can force it to run, this is just an observation on bazel's understanding of the build graph).

Comment: Maybe the source directory is in your PYTHONPATH? You could try running bazel with `--incompatible_strict_action_env`

Comment: Test still passes with that flag. Here is the `sys.path` within the test (trimmed):
```
['workspace', 'sandbox/linux-sandbox/3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo_test.runfiles', 'sandbox/linux-sandbox/3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo_test.runfiles/bazel_tools', 'sandbox/linux-sandbox/3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo_test.runfiles/__main__', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

The workspace root is included first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [know issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/issues/382) with rules_python, with a [prior solution](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/python/python_stub_template.txt#L19) that is, unfortunately, [currently broken](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7091#issuecomment-561908692).

A simple workaround is to just repeat the fix from the python_stub, i.e. make the file content

```py
import sys
sys.path.pop(0)

import foo
foo.foo()
```

and then `bazel test //:foo_test --test_output=all` will fail with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'` as expected, until you add `:foo` as dep in the BUILD.

Another workaround is to move your test file to a `tests/` subdir so that the script dir (that the Python interpreter [will always add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621527/prevent-script-dir-from-being-added-to-sys-path-in-python-3#comment96062343_54621619) to the sys.path) will not contain any (spurious) dependencies.